# Javascript redirect not functioning after form submit. Asp Classic, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

Alright, after hours and hours of research and trying things I am completely stuck at the moment. I coded quite a lot for a web page so I'll try to summarize it as good as possible.

So I've got this ASP CLASSIC page where a user can create a ticket using a form. 
The coded page consists out of 3 main parts:

1. Javascript client side error handling.
2. ASP CLASSIC server side error handling after submission (checking if
   database values exists like email).
3. The form submitting (sending an email + inserting the data into the
   database).

After the form is submitted there is some ASP error handling. When a error is encountered a Javascript popup box will be shown with the error and the data submission and email is being cancelled.

The form is auto filled with the inputted values (with asp code) so that after a error the inputted values are kept in the form. This all works.

**The form code:**

```
<div align="left"><form name="myForm" method="post" style="display:inline" onsubmit="return(validate());"> 


    <div class="FormTitel">Voor welke afdeling is de ticket bestemd?
    </div>


    <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="automatisering" value="Automatisering" checked <% if Request.Form("automatisering") = "Automatisering" then response.write("checked")%>>Automatisering
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="automatisering" value="Software" <% if Request.Form("automatisering") = "Software" then response.write("checked")%>>Software
    <div id="Error1" style="display:none" color="white"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="FormTitel">Soort ticket
    </div>
     <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio"  class="radio" name="probleem" value="Probleem" <% if Request.Form("probleem") = "Probleem" then response.write("checked")%>>Probleem
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="probleem" value="Wijziging"<% if Request.Form("probleem") = "Wijziging" then response.write("checked")%>>Wijziging
    <div id="Error2" style="display:none" color="white"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="FormTitel">Uw gegevens
    </div>
    <div>   
    <input type="text" name="Name" class="name" placeholder="Vul hier uw voor- en achternaam in" style="color:#888;" 
    onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" value="<%=Request.Form("Name")%>">
    <div id="Error3" style="display:none" color="white"></div>
    </div>
    <div>       
    <input type="text" name="EMail" class="name" placeholder="Vul hier uw emailadres in" style="color:#888;" 
    onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" value="<%=Request.Form("EMail")%>"/>
    <div id="Error4" style="display:none" color="white"></div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="ticketVerstuur" value="Verstuur ticket" />  
        </form></div>
```

*The error id's are client side styling boxes that are being showed when a Validation returns false (with javascript). 
*Sorry for not translating the title's, names, etc. but that would be quite some work;)

The ASP IF statements in the form make sure that the inputted values are returned and not lost when a error is being showed.

Alright now for the part where it goes wrong.

After submission, which is being activated by If `Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then` some stuff is happening. Namely, the input values are being parameterized for sql injection, some input values are being checked on the server side, for example; does the submitted email exists in the database? and if the server side validation is all fine then the data is being inserted in the database and a email is being send.

The error messages on the server side are being shown to the user as javascript popup boxes. This works.

The javascript popup code:

```
function popup(popup,container) {

        var thisPopup = this;            

        thisPopup.load = function() {            

            container.animate({
                "opacity": "0.3"  
            },250, function() {            
                popup.fadeIn("250");            
            });    

            container.off("click").on("click", function() {
                thisPopup.unload();
            }); 

            $('#closePop').off("click").on("click", function() {            
                thisPopup.unload();             
            });                              
        }       

        thisPopup.unload = function() {            

            popup.fadeOut("250", function(){
                container.animate({
                    "opacity": "1"  
                },250);  
            });
        }
    }
```

The function is called in the submit code like so:  `new popup($("#popup_box"),$("#container")).load();` The popup div is put above the form and the container is wrapped around the form. (popup works).

The problem though is that after the server side validation is all good, so the data goes into the database and the email is send, I popup a new javascript box saying that the everything was successful. When it is successful I want to clear my form (to avoid confusion).

First I try'd to do this with a `response.redirect ("mypage.asp")`. Though, when I use this the javascript popup box wont show. 
Then I try'd to use a `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");` on my close / unload function of the popup box, this has no effect though (data is not being cleared). Also try'd it with setting a var to true when the popup is unloaded and then later checking the var if it is set to true (then redirect) but this also doesn't work, even a direct javascript redirect, so without the popup, in the submission code (after all is successful) doesn't seem to work for some reason. In matter of fact only alert seems to work. Here the example of the adjusted popup unload:

```
    thisPopup.unload = function() {            

window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

popup.fadeOut("250", function(){
                    container.animate({
                        "opacity": "1"  
                    },250);  
                });
            }
```

So what causes this problem and how can I fix it? I can imagine it requires a bit more of my code so don't hesitate to ask for it, but the post is big enough as it is.

Last but not least a short summary of how my code is setup:

```
<html>
<head>
    stylesheet
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<javascript>
    Pop up box code + validate form code
</javascript>
<form>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<asp server side code (on submit)>
   Some functions (mail - anti injection) + request form values
   Validation server side (with javascript poups)
   Insert data in database
   Sending mail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with the redirect. To get a pop-up to show after a redirect, do something like this:

```
response.redirect "mypage.asp?ShowSuccess=true"
```

Then in mypage.asp use this:

```
<%
if request("ShowSuccess") = "true" then
    onload = "alert('Success message here!');"
end if
%>
<body onload="<%=onload%>">
```

Comment: Good idea! This can indeed do it.  Thanks!